# What are the basics for a login system

Tags: mysql, database, authentication, login-system

I am working on a project about Log-in System. I want to know what are the basics of the Log-in System including its authenticating methods in order to be called "Advanced" Log-in System.

Comment: The question is very vague, please be more precise.

Comment: remove your down vote please

Comment: We are downvoting only to indicate that your question needs to be refined so that we can give you better answers. "I'm working on a project that it's about login system" is not telling much about what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to implement a reusable authentication system? Are you trying to design  a login system for one of your applications? What have you considered so far and why you think you need an *advanced* login system? I will remove my downvote as soon as you improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, you need password confirmation, secret question and answer for password reseting, check if the user admin or not, check if blocked or not, password strength depends on the character typed, etc.